# insert data into a table - jsp error

Tags: jsp, insert

I need some help with inserting data into a database. Here's what I have ATM:

```
<%@  page  language="java"  import="java.sql.*" %>

    <%
String url=  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reclamacoes";
String titulo=request.getParameter("titulo"); 
String reclamacao=request.getParameter("reclamacao"); 


  try  {  
        String  insert  = "INSERT  INTO  reclamacoes  (id_utilizador, titulo, reclamacao)" + "VALUES  (?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?)";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,  "root",  "root");

        PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement(insert);  
        ps.setString(1,  session.getAttribute("id"));  
        ps.setString(2,  titulo);  
        ps.setString(3,  reclamacao);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.close();  
  }catch  (ExcepLon  ex)  {
        out.println ("ERRO:  Insert"); 
  }
```

%>

And it gives me this error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file:
>   /recurso/grava_reclamacao.jsp The method setString(int, String) in the
>   type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int,
>   Object) 12:             Connection con =
>   DriverManager.getConnection(url,  "root",  "root"); 13:  14:
>   PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement(insert);   15:
>   ps.setString(1,  session.getAttribute("id"));   16:
>   ps.setString(2,  titulo);   17:             ps.setString(3, 
>   reclamacao); 18:             ps.executeUpdate();
>
> An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file:
>   /recurso/grava_reclamacao.jsp ExcepLon cannot be resolved to a type
>   17:             ps.setString(3,  reclamacao); 18:
>   ps.executeUpdate(); 19:             con.close();   20:       }catch 
>   (ExcepLon  ex)  { 21:             out.println ("ERRO:  Insert");  22: 
>   } 23: %>
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:476)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I can't find the error on the connection line, it seems okay to me. Do I need any other package than the jdbc Driver ?

Thanks people

Comment: What is `ExcepLon` here? Is it your custom class if yes then import it in JSP if not then change it to `Exception`. Look at the logs again `An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file:` and what is at line no `20: }catch (ExcepLon ex)`

Comment: In your `insert`, you are inserting values into 3 columns and still you have specified 5 values `values(?,?,?,?,?)`..this is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<%@  page  language="java"  import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String url=  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reclamacoes";
String titulo=request.getParameter("titulo"); 
String reclamacao=request.getParameter("reclamacao");

try{
    String  insert  = "INSERT  INTO "
                    + " reclamacoes(id_utilizador, titulo, reclamacao) "
                    + "VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,  "root",  "root");
    PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement(insert);
    String id = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
    ps.setString(1, id );
    ps.setString(2, titulo);
    ps.setString(3, reclamacao);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception ex){
   out.print(ex);
}
```

Comment: Hey! that worked, thanks a lot :p The Int i could not find that error... but the ExcepLon, i found it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First error:

> The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)

You need to typecast what you pull out of the session since by default it comes out as Object:

```
ps.setString(1,  (String)session.getAttribute("id"));
```

Second error:

> ExcepLon cannot be resolved to a type

In your catch block you misspelled `Exception` as "ExcepLon"